# document.location Question

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

I need some help with document.location. Basically, I need a button, using document.location, with the URL hide://. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: what do you what to do? Be more specific....

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you want? Do you want a button to be linked with document.location? I don't understand why you would need that

Comment: Yes, thats right. linked with document.location

Comment: I want a button to be linked with document.location to hide://

Comment: You want to set the current `document.location` to `hide://`? It's not possible, there is no `hide` protocol, thus it isn't a valid URL...

Comment: I know that. Its not a valid URL. then make it google.com please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button value="click me" onclick="document.location='hide://'" />
```

or am i missing something?

edit : as CMS has mentioned, `hide://` is not a valid url. i'm not sure what you want to do, OP, but hopefully that snippet will set you on the right path...